# Add class to span if it contains a decimal number

Tags: jquery, css, decimal

I have a list of links as follows:

```
<span><span class="prefix">1.</span>xxx</span>
<span><span class="prefix">2.</span>xxx</span>
<span><span class="prefix">2.1.</span>xxx</span>
<span><span class="prefix">10.</span>xxx</span>
```

I want to add a class to the .prefix elements of that list which contains a decimal number. So far, I have reached the point where I count characters, and if > 2, class in added. But of course then the 10+ numbers are affected as well, and they shouldn't...

```
$(function() {
  $(".sub-menu span[class*='prefix']").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass($(this).text().length > 2 ? "sub" : "dom");
  });
});
```

I basically need to know how to treat the .text() element to discriminate between decimal and non decimal. The problem is I'm using a dot (".") as decimal comma, but *also* at the end of each numer -- so I can't even use something like ":contains:'.'" I guess what I need to do is to specify a discrete series of dots as discriminators between decimal and non decimal.

Comment: Which of those values are you expecting to be valid/invalid?

Comment: you could use `str.indexOf('.')`

Comment: I'd like the class "sub" to be added to decimal elements, the class "dom" to non-decimal.

Comment: That doesn't answer my previous question.

Comment: if you need to find the `.` which is followed by a number, you can use `match` instead

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - It is relevant in the way, that he can check if the string contains a `.` use it with conditionals, to add a class, if it exists.

Comment: Still doesn't help. Given `2.1` and `2.1.1` the `indexOf('.')` will be the same. How do you differentiate?

Comment: Check the number of `.`s; if its > 1, add the "sub" class.

Comment: thats why I suggested Match instead

Comment: so you can use a regex

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It's always `2.1.` or `2.`, never `2.1.1` or `2.1.1.`, at least, that's how I read it. Would be nice if he answered your original question though :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey that's why I asked the OP to clarify what should/should not be valid, as from what I can see, all of the examples they show should be valid. They seem to have disappeared and left an annoying question which is far too open to interpretation though.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan There can only be one decimal dot (the final dot is merely typographic). I don't understand the valid/invalid question, I'm sorry (and probably too limited). For example "2." should be applied the class "dom" ; 2.1. the class" sub".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With match you should be able to do this, since you can use regular expressions.

Sadly regex isn't my strong suit. So i am not sure that it is correctly written, but the logic is there

```
$(function() {
  $(".sub-menu span[class*='prefix']").each(function() {
    var currentText = $(this).text();
    //$(this).addClass($(this).text().length > 2 ? "sub" : "dom");
    if( currentText.match(/\.\d+/g) ).length{
        //Do something - like adding the class
   }
   else{
        //Do something else - or skip
   }

  });
});
```

The regex here, should only be true if `.`is present, and is followed by a digit.

Meaning that `2.1` is true

`2.1.3` is true

`2.` is false

`2.1.5.`is false

But maybe somebody can help with the regex

Comment: This might be a bit safer: /^[0-9]+.?$/g The regex checks if the start is any number with any count followed by an optional dot and nothing after the dot. E.g. Ten. would be false while it would be with Stenders Solution still true

Comment: @Sven Like I said - I suck at Regex :-D

Comment: No Problem, thats what the community is for - helping each other to get better :) :D

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your numbers will be valid numbers, (e.g: not 1.2.3, etc) you can check the module of this number by 1.

```
$(function() {
  $(".sub-menu span[class*='prefix']").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass(Number($(this).text()) % 1 ? "sub" : "dom");
  });
});
```

Any integer % 1 = 0
Any decimal % 1 > 0 (Unless it's something like 3.0 which could be represented as just 3)

Answer (score 0):

You have to try following code :

```
    $(function() {
       $(".sub-menu span[class*='prefix']").each(function() {
         var num = $(this).text();
         if(num % 1 != 0)
           $(this).addClass("xyz")  
      });
   });
```